# Resizing JFrame in Window 7 - Java

Tags: java

I have question about resizing JFrame in windows 7 ,

After i drag my frame to top of my window/monitor and release mouse button, 
sometimes frame stuck/freeze, sometimes don't.
So i need to drag frame to unstuck it

What is problem, how to fix it ?

black color is when frame is frozen

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameTest extends JFrame
{
    public JFrameTest()
    {
        setTitle("Frame Example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JFrameTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

so i get this result after resize this program for ex...
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/652/35945338.png

Comment: You probably have some custom code that is creating the problem. We can't guess what this might be. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: any JFrame behaves the same, no matter on source code

Comment: when this happen, whole frame is frozen

http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/652/35945338.png

why this is happening ? i don't know :S

Comment: The problem is your code. Without a SSCCE we can't help!!!

Comment: Sample code please.  Doesn't happen to me, Runing Windows 7 x64, Java 7 and Java 6 no issues

Comment: It could be hardware graphics acceleration not working properly.  Try running with `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` option and see if the problem continues.